# How to count child users against each parent

Tags: sql, database

I need to count this against my each parent_id instead of a specific parent_id as given below in where clause ..

```
select count(*), U_ID 
from ( 
    select `users`.`u_id` AS U_ID 
    from `users` inner join `referrals` on `users`.`u_id` = `referrals`.`child_u_id` 
    where `referrals`.`level` = 1 
        and `referrals`.`parent_id` = '15254' 
        and `users`.`plan` = 2 
     group by `referrals`.`child_u_id`
) AS t.
```

here `15254` is a specific user.. and i want this count for all my users list

it gives me following result and i want it for my all users

```
Count(*) |  U_Id

3        | 15254
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you're new to this platform. But for other to help you, try to be considerate to be help. Read some tips about using stackoverflow, so as to present your difficulties better and to get quicker and clearer answers. Saying this, I think you need to omit that you filtered it in the where clause to display the results of only that user_id. So you may try this, and finally group it by u_id.

```
select count(*), U_ID 
from ( 
    select `users`.`u_id` AS U_ID 
    from `users` inner join `referrals` on `users`.`u_id` = `referrals`.`child_u_id` 
    where `referrals`.`level` = 1 
        ---and `referrals`.`parent_id` = '15254' 
        and `users`.`plan` = 2 
     group by `referrals`.`child_u_id`
) AS t
Group by u_Id
```

Comment: thanks for advice. . please can u help me little more.. if i want to put this clause ,, "where Count > 5"  where should i put it ??

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you want to filter after the count is grouped by, you can do it at the end. Otherwise, you can filter it before the count is done.

Comment: please can u elaborate it little more.. i am trying this 




[[ select count(*) as C ,U_ID
 from (
select R.`parent_u_id` AS U_ID 
from `users` as U INNER join `referrals` as R on U.`u_id` = R.`child_u_id` where R.`level` = 1  
and U.`plan` = 2 
group BY R.child_u_id) as t 
 WHERE `C` >= 5
 Group by U_ID 

]]


but it gives me error "Unknown column 'C' "

Comment: To use C out side of the sub query, you should mention it in the sub query. Select r.parent_u_id as u_id, C from users.....

Comment: it gives me same error again    "Unknown column 'C' in 'field list' "

Answer (score 0):

i have achieve my target by this query ..

`

```
select count(*) as C,U_ID 
from (
     select R.`parent_u_id` AS U_ID
     from `users` as U INNER join `referrals` as R on U.`u_id` = R.`child_u_id`
      where R.`level` = 1  
      and U.`plan` = 2
     group BY R.child_u_id
)
 as t 
 Group by U_ID
  HAVING C >= 5
```

`